# Creating dynamic attributes using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an e-commerce web app for managing/storing products and
categories.

The products-categories screen should include the following fields:

- Category Name: Text
- Parent Category: a multi-level tree
- Category: **dynamic attributes** (e.g. Size, Colors, Width, weight, etc...) for
  the below types:

  - Text
  - Multiline
  - Options
  - Yes/ No

I am confused about the best way to make my database and my code do these dynamic attributes.
For example, to insert a new category, the user will enter in the text field the "size" attribute and choose its type from the drop-down menu I made.

My question is:
How do I add this attribute into the database structure at runtime?

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, thanks for your question. For best results, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and update your answer with more context.

Comment: How about an Attribute Table, with `DataType` (Enum), `Value` (String/Json/Xml) and `CategoryId` (1 to n for categroy)?